# Sum cummulative period from others table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have table transaction below

```
Product Qty    Date         
A       100    01/01/2017
A       100    03/01/2017
A       200    04/01/2017 
A       100    05/01/2017
B       100    07/01/2017
B        50    08/01/2017
B       200    10/01/2017
B       100    17/01/2017
C       100    20/01/2017
C       300    21/01/2017
C       150    24/01/2017
```

and I have table delivery date

```
Period    Month   startdate   enddate     deliverydate
Period1   Jan     01/01/2017  15/01/2017  17/01/2017
Period2   Jan     16/01/2017  31/01/2017  04/02/2017
```

And I want the result like this

```
Product TotalQty    DeliveryDate
A       500         17/01/2017
B       350         17/01/2017
B       100         04/02/2017
C       550         04/02/2017
```

And I am confused how to create the query to get that result.
Can you guys help me on this ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything? For example a query deciding which transaction belongs to which DeliveryDate?

Comment: Speaking of which, you should at least try to explain how your result is to be constructed; writing this down (for us) will probably help you understand your problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this

```
DECLARE @Transaction AS TABLE (Product varchar(10), Qty int, [Date] date)
INSERT INTO @Transaction
VALUES ('A', 100, '2017-01-01'), ('A', 100, '2017-01-03'), ('A', 200, '2017-01-04'), ('A', 100, '2017-01-05'),
('B', 100, '2017-01-07'),('B', 50, '2017-01-08'),('B', 200, '2017-01-10'),('B', 100, '2017-01-17'),
('C', 100, '2017-01-20'),('C', 300, '2017-01-21'),('C', 150, '2017-01-24')


DECLARE @Delivery AS TABLE (startdate date, enddate date, deliverydate date)
INSERT INTO @Delivery VALUES ('2017-01-01', '2017-01-15', '2017-01-17'), ('2017-01-16', '2017-01-31', '2017-02-04')


SELECT t.Product,SUM(t.Qty) AS TotalQty , d.DeliveryDate  
FROM @Transaction t
INNER JOIN @Delivery d ON t.[Date] >= d.startdate AND t.[Date] <= d.enddate
GROUP BY t.Product,d.DeliveryDate
```

Demo link: [Rextester](http://rextester.com/MHRN50445)

Comment: Thanks a lota, now I  understand